# Transactions Won’t Confirm

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have an offline wallet and I wanted to send some bitcoins to myself on an account I have on one of the exchanges. I sent a small amount 6 days ago and it still hasn’t gone through. I’m not sure why it’s taking so long and was wondering if anyone had any tips. I made a mistake of not adding a fee to it so I resent another small amount to my exchange based wallet with a fee of .0005 and that one hasn’t gone through either even though its been 5 days. Is there a way to reset the transactions or something so I can try again?

My transaction ID is: `2e0e6fcc39596707e6566b22c2806d68ca9d57117f43f1eeb31514c059b1e962`

Comment: How about telling transaction ID?

Comment: 2e0e6fcc39596707e6566b22c2806d68ca9d57117f43f1eeb31514c059b1e962

Comment: That transaction hasn't been seen by blockchain.info.  I entered it into my Bitcoin-Qt client and it said it was an invalid transaction ID.  Sounds like your transaction was never broadcast to the network.

Comment: It would help if you described the steps you took to send the coins from your offline wallet.

Comment: i opened up my bitcoin client, copy+paste the address to send it to (i have double checked multiple times to make sure its correct and it is), typed in my key to be able to send them and sent them. the bitcoins are no longer in my wallet and the transaction is showing in the client but with a ? mark and when I look at the info amongst other things it says 0/unconfirmed and sometimes its be broadcast through x number of nodes. is there a way to cancel these transactions so i can get the balance back and try sending them again?